# Can you embeed 3d pdf in js/html?

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to embed 3d pdf into html with using js or without?

I tried by doing this with standard `embed` for pdf but this gives me a whitescreen inside `embed` area rather than actual 3d pdf view..

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <embed src="UR5i_v2F_SL_DGA.PDF" width="500" height="505" type='application/pdf'>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried PDF.js??

Comment: Yeah but sadly I need solution to be local without any server

Comment: Not sure what kind of support 3D PDF requires (I.e. if you are supposed to be able to open it with any PDF viewer, or if you need specific support), but the issue may be related to the PDF viewer embedded in your browser. Have you tried different browsers? Have you tried using `object` or `iframe` instead of `embed`?

Comment: @jcaron yeah I have, same result..